# Google chrome app icon not showing up in the default app drawer after distro upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, gnome-shell-extension, 21.10

I first upgraded my distro from 20.04 LTS to 21.04 and then to 21.10 two days back. Ever since i'm facing some problems.At first i had to reinstall firefox and spotify apps because they were missing in the updated version. Today i woke up to see that the google chrome icon is missing from Ubuntu 21.10 app-drawer although the app is installed.

First of all, how do i fix this google chrome icon issue? Second, what's the reason for this malfunctioning since the distro upgrade? What's the permanent fix to these recurring issues as i fear tomorrow it could be a new issue?
Related info - I installed a few popular gnome shell extensions like Just Perfection, Overview Navigation, Switcher, Tiling assistant and Hide Top Bar via google chrome prior to facing these problems, if that helps maybe.

Comment: How did you upgrade from 20.04 to 21.10?  Ubuntu *upgrade* tools currently only allow upgrades from 21.04 to 21.10; so you've implied errors in details you provided - or you *forced* the upgrade and thus what you did to your system may provide clues (as you're outside of QA-tested procedures currently).  If you want a perfect *release-upgrade* path; I'd suggest using tools that are QA-tested & using the QA-tested upgrade paths.

Comment: Start debugging your problems by disabling all your extensions, and enabling them one by one. I had problems with Just Perfection in this version, so look there first. Also confirm whether you still can run Chrome from the command line. It is known that an upgrade can cause issues. Chances are higher the more a system is customized. I survived it pretty well, though.

Comment: I have the same issue. My Chrome icon, as well as many other app icons, are missing from the app drawer after the upgrade. I do not use any gnome extensions and I do not use any custom themes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @michaeljdennis I found out that the icons were moved to the 'favourites' category, which is why i couldn't see them in the app drawer. It seems icons cannot be in the app drawer and 'favourites' at the same time. I suggest you first check if the apps that are missing their icons are even installed on your system or not in the first place. If they're installed you should see if the icons are moved to a different category like 'favourites' or not.If you still can't find the icons but you have the apps installed, i think you should purge remove the apps and reinstall the apps as a last resort.

Comment: @skekmal thank you for the reply. I had no idea that the functionality had changed to where apps added to favorites no longer show up in the app drawer. I tested by removing an app from favorites and it showed up in the app drawer as expected. Thanks again!